# git branch commit how to ignore modified files

Tags: git, git-branch

Hello I was working on a branch of a symfony project ( private directory )

I did modify config.yml to check translations ..

On commit it showed me ( tracked files from the master )

```
modified : app/config/config.yml , .gitignore
```

I did

```
git rm --cached app/config/config.yml , .gitignore
```

then

```
git commit and git push
```

now those files shows as "deleted' within github branch ..

Is there any way to discard this deletion and just ignore local changes to theses files ??

I did tried with :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  app/config/config.yml
```

but returned : can't mark file

my .gitignore allready lists both files, but seems to have no effect ..

Thanks in advance for your enlightment on my question, as I'm really stucked now

Comment: is the repository public on github? can you link it so that we can better understand what you want to change?

Comment: the answer was :

git revert.


then git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>

Answer (score 0):

you didn't commit yet, right?

try:

```
git reset HEAD app/config/config.yml
```

edit: read just now: you did `git commit` and `git push` already. You are pretty much screwed. You shouldn't modify pushed commits, but you can make a revert commit like this:

```
git stash
git checkout HEAD^ app/config/config.yml
git add app/config/config.yml
git commit -m "reverting removal of config.yml" #(or whatever commit message you want)
git stash pop
```

Comment: there is also another pretty dangerous command to actually change the history as if the commit never happened, but you should use this only if you are ABSOLUTELY SURE noone has checked out your revision yet. It involves REMOVING the remote branch, then REVERTING LOCALLY the commits, then pushing back the reverted branch again

Comment: Well, I used github for windows at home, reverted this change, this far.


Then git update-index --assume-unchanged  app/config/config.yml worked like a Charm :)


Thanks for your answer, I was kinda lost & alone on git island :)